# How to find "possible friends" from the user's contacts

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Suppose I have some user's contacts(like contacts in the phone). And in the contacts, a user will have their friends's contact info(like phone number) in it.Not big we can suppose it is less than 1000.

If in A's contact, A has B's contact info, we say A and B are friends(even though B does not have A).

Now, we consider if User1 and User2  have more than two common friends User3 and User4 or more, we say User1 and User2 are possible friends(if User1 and User2 are not friends).

And we have n user's contacts. How to find all of these users's possible friends.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about that : get the number of paths possible between UserA and UserB, and then if number>2, userA and userB are possible friends.

First of all, you need to create the adjacency matrix of your graph (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix)

Something like that :

```
//Numbers of edges
int n = 5;

int[][] adjacencymatrix = new int[][] {
    new int[] {1,1,1,0,0}, //    1
    new int[] {1,1,1,1,0}, //  / | \
    new int[] {1,1,1,1,0}, // 0  |  3 - 4
    new int[] {0,1,1,1,1}, //  \ | /
    new int[] {0,0,0,1,1}, //    2
};
```

Then, a few more stuff

```
// stock the path
int[] path = new int[n];

// lock for the search (all at false at the beginning)
boolean[] taboo = new boolean[n];

// start and stop edges
int source=0;
int target=4;
```

And finally :

```
void explore(int position, int depth) {
    path[depth]=position;

    // arrived at stop point -> finished
    if (position==target) {
        // print the solution
        for(int i=0;i<=depth;i++) System.out.print(path[i]+" ");
        System.out.print("\n");
        return;
    }

    taboo[position]=true; // remember you already went on this edge

    // explore remaining paths
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        if (adjacencymatrix[position][i]==0 || taboo[i]) continue;
        explore(i,depth+1);
    }

    taboo[position]=false;
}
```

Basically what it does is find all the unique paths from UserA to UserB.
Hope this will help you!

Comment: You must have an additional restriction - paths' length must `=1`, because, in your case, `0` and `4` don't have friends in common, but they will become `possible friends`, what isn't correct

Answer (score 0):

Let `G` be the undirected graph where the vertex set is the contacts and (a,b) is an edge iff `a` is a friend of `b` (i.e. `a` is a contact in `b`'s list or the other way).

Then the problem is simply finding two distinct paths from `a` to `b`. Such paths can be found by:

1. Run DFS starting with `a`
2. Whenever you visit `b` during the search, print its path.
3. Stop when your program outputs two paths.

The issue is you may not find such paths and this would make the problem hard in general.